# Can a subprocess hand data to Tensorflow directly without going through the main Python process (avoiding GIL lock)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, subprocess

I'm working with a high IO model (a single GPU can chew on 600 MB/sec of uncompressible data). It requires about 4 CPU cores to handle the IO alone, so the main training loop process can't do it.

Currently, I have multiple subprocesses that sample data from a distributed filesystem and write to local tfrecords files (the dataset size exceeds local storage). My main training process uses a `TFRecordsDataset` & `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` to iterate over the files as they are written to disk.

It works, but writing to disk just to read it again is clearly suboptimal. I wonder if there's a better approach that can use subprocesses to hand off samples directly to Tensorflow. I can't pass the data to the main training process via Python because it requires more than 1 CPU core to just move that much data, and Python's GIL bottlenecks.

I attempted to write data to named pipes, but the TFRecordsDataset performs seek operations and thus couldn't read from pipes, only files. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you use shared memory combined with either `from_tensors` (or `from_tensor_slices`) or `from_generator` with a custom generator? The `TFRecordDataset` was made for being backed by a file explicitly.

Comment: Python 3.8 shared memory does seem like the best solution, TF 2.2 is almost here with 3.8 support. I am looking forward to that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that come to mind.

If you haven't already done so, put the local data on an SSD (NVMe if possible). That gives a significant speedup without needing any code changes.

You could try reading/writing the local files with `mmap`. The OS will then keep the most recently accessed pages in memory; as many as will fit in the disk cache. If one program writes the data and others read it, it's like shared memory but with a file-like interface.

You could use sockets to transfer the data between processes.

See e.g. this [pytables example](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/master/examples/multiprocess_access_benchmarks.py).

If you are on a UNIX-like system you could use POSIX shared memory via `ctypes`. Of course if you could use 3.8's shared memory from `multiprocessing`, that is probably a lot easier.

Comment: I've taken it down to the socket level to get data into the main process, but it costs too much CPU still to move data that fast and the GIL becomes a bottleneck, you need more than 1 core to do even socket based transfer of the data. The local disk is NVMe, but it's 500 GB and the dataset is 3TB, so local storage of the entire dataset isn't an option. It really is necessary to bypass Python, the GIL is a major limitation in Python. The NVMe is capable of handling the write-then-read IO, which is what I do now, it's just not ideal. Currently I keep a 100GB rotating subset of samples local.

Comment: I must be missing something because the GIL shouldn't be a factor when moving data between processes, unless you're using `multiprocessing` or `threading`. Your post explicitly mentions `subprocess` but not `multiprocessing` or `threading`.

Comment: I did a very low level test to see how fast I could move data between python processes using sockets. I got 4GB/sec moving which used a full core on the read side. That was reading and discarding. The moment I even joined byte arrays on the read size the speed halved to 2GB/sec with a full core utilized on the read side. When I tried this with higher level tools like python Pipe and tried to feed tensorflow I always locked up the CPU on the main training process. The problem becomes CPU bound just on the deserialization process.

Comment: When I write to a tfrecords file and let tensorflow read using `TFReacordDataset` the CPU sits at 400% on the training process, but that's in Tensorflow, outside of Python's GIL. So basic serialization operations on my real-world data rate require about 4 cores. Which tensorflow can parallelize just fine, but a single Python process cannot (limited to about 1 core due to the GIL)

Comment: Notably, Python 3.8 shared memory should solve this in theory because you no longer need to serialize when transferring data between processes, you just pass a trivially small string pointer. But since 3.8 is not yet supported in tensorflow I wanted to verify there wasn't another option I missed.

Comment: Why not use POSIX or system V shared memory via `ctypes`?

Comment: Yup, but that's only in Python 3.8, which is technically supported in Tensorflow 2.2.0rc2 now, but it's still in active development. I'm not aware that system V shared memory is possible pre-Python 3.8. That does seem like the best solution.